# Change max recursion default value in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have problem with creating view, while using max recursion option. Can I change default value of max recursion in SQL server, without writing 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) ?

Comment: I'm pretty confident in saying no. The default is there for a reason; mainly as a safeguard. If someone wrote some poor SQL and you had your Server's default set to `MAXRECURSION 0`, you could just end up pulling the server down. You should only change the `MAXRECURSION` value on queries that need it; not on a "global" scale.

Comment: Thank you. and how can i avoid this problem: error while creating view using recursion?

Comment: When selecting from the `VIEW`, you'll need to include the option: So: `SELECT * FROM [YourView] OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);`.